# How to get the application name for a window reference

Tags: applescript

When I get the reference to a window using for example:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theWindow to first window
end tell

log(process(theWindow)) -- # Safari

tell application "Terminal"
    set theWindow to first window
end tell

log(process(theWindow)) -- # Terminal

to process(theWindow)
    -- How to get app name from "theWindow"
end process
```

From the variable `theWindow`, is it possible to extract the app name "Safari"? I need to know this information from a handler because the handler can accept window reference of other application as well.

Comment: How does this *window reference* look like?

Comment: I'll update the code, so it makes more sense...

Comment: This makes no sense. Any `window` belongs to an application. Without an application tell block you cannot access the object, so it's an xy problem. At the moment you get the window you actually know the application. And in an UI based environment (`System Events`) you have to know the process to access a window.

Comment: Well, I am hoping I could find something similar to HTML, or other UI frameworks where an element could simply access its parent. You are saying it it's nonesense based on what, that AS was designed that way?

Comment: `HTML` is plain text. AppleScript is binary compiled code. A `window` is a **class** (an object) of this compiled code. You can get the `parent` attribute from a window in `System Events` but you need to address the window by its process. And since you have the process you have the name. I don't see the benefit of the generic handler as you are generating the window in the application which you know the name of.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is when I created this handler that accepts a window object coming from a `tell app "application". It turned out what I want is a window from a `tell app SysEve to tell process appName` There's quite a lot, so rather than fixing all of it, I was looking for quick fix to it. Thank you for your explanation, it looks like I would need to fix it the long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theWindow to first window
end tell

log (process(theWindow))

tell application "Terminal"
    set theWindow to first window
end tell

log (process(theWindow)) -- # Terminal

to process(theWindow)
    try
        theWindow as text
    on error errorMessage
    end try
    set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
    set appName to text item 2 of errorMessage
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    return appName
end process
```